# viewer.js / pdf.js: Memory usage increases every time a pdf is rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, memory, pdf.js

My problem is that the memory usage of my application increases every time I render a pdf file with viewer.js.

I render my pdf this way:

```
container = document.getElementById('viewerContainer');
viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');

pdfViewer = new PDFViewer({
    container: container,
    viewer: viewer
});

$scope.pdfFindController = new PDFFindController({
      pdfViewer: pdfViewer
});

pdfViewer.setFindController($scope.pdfFindController);

container.addEventListener('pagesinit', function () {
    pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = 'page-width';                            
});

PDFJS.getDocument($scope.getPageLink(pdf)).then(function (pdfDocument) {
    documentPdf = pdfDocument;
    pdfViewer.setDocument(pdfDocument);                       
});
```

I render the file in a separate view. When I go back to my previous view and open another file, the memory usage increases by ~20MB.

I tried this:

```
documentPdf.destroy();
```

Now, the memory usage decreases a bit, but not as much as it was allocated before.

Is there a solution for this?

**UPDATE**:

Pdf.js version: 1.6.210

pdf.js worker version: 1.6.210

Comment: Make sure you measure memory after garbage collection was run. (Some browsers can force to GC via their tools to do that). It's recommended to use the same PDFWorker is you are trying to use multiple docs on the same page. `documentPdf.destroy();` is right step. If you don't re-use the same pdfViewer for setDocument, make sure you cleanup all refs to the old one including pdfFindController.

Comment: There is no angularjs package available from pdfjs project. It's hard to tell or reproduce if no complete example is provided or the package (vendor) used are mentioned.

Comment: I use Xcode to see the memory usage. Because I build it for iOS. The PDFWorker should be the same. I just set the reference every time `PDFJS.workerSrc = 'lib/pdfviewer/pdf.worker.js';`. I deleted and set the variables like Giovazz89 recommended. Could it be that viewer.js /pdf.js still has some references? Actually, they should be overwritten and I destroy the document in that file, too. Is it possible to clear all variables in one file?

Comment: Looks like the issue with iOS. Do you see the same issue on a regular browser? You did not publish Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example -- this might help to troubleshot  your solution.

Comment: It's a bit complicated. I can't start it in my browser, because my app needs another app to work. Unfortunately, I do not have time to build an example. I'll try but I can't promise.

Answer (score 13):

You need to call the destroy method on the promise of the DocumentPageProxy.

The documentation describes it as followed:

> Destroys current document instance and terminates worker.
>
> Source: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js (Line 621)

There are some tests in the current `pdf.js` library, which tests the behaviour of the destroy method. (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/test/unit/api_spec.js (Line 86)

In your case something like:

```
 // a variable to store the callback function
 var loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(basicApiUrl);
 
...

 // when the document should get destroyed call
 loadingTask.destroy();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is obsolete for me now, because I will use the cordova pdf viewer plugin which works much better than pdf.js: https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer

Comment: I had the same issue, and analyzed it in pdf.js - then i found your post and at least i answered it. Sometimes i answer other posts for my personal documentation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that by calling `documentPdf.destroy();` you don't free the memory taken by `pdfViewer`:
I didn't find any methods to destroy `pdfViewer`, but you can try to call

```
delete pdfViewer;
delete documentPdf;
```

and if you are not confident that deleting properties is enough, you can set both to `null`.

If you still experience memory leaks it can be that the HTML stored in the history cache is using up your memory, so try to replace the viewer or container HTML with an empty element (or remove it completely)

```
document.getElementById('viewerContainer').outerHTML = '';
```

or

```
container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, the memory still increases...

Comment: Have you tried deleting event the $scope.pdfFindController variable? I hope it isn't keepeng other object instances

Comment: I tried `$scope.pdfFindController = null` and `delete $scope.pdfFindController`. Did not work... Is there may a difference between `null` and `undefined`?

Comment: It should not: by doing `delete` first, you destroy the object properties, and by setting it to `null` or `undefined` right after, the variable get completely wiped...but you say that you render the file in a separate view: is it a popup or a separate window? Then you have to run it before it closes (before unload, even starting all with the removing HTML element thing, followed by clearing JS objects)